# Which reps sold the part with description: ROCKING HORSE? [Ensure both sides are in UPPER case for comparison]

Tags: sql

This is a SQL homework problem.  As far as entities involved, there are five involved:  rep r, customer c, orders o, order_line ol, and item i.  They are connected as follows;  c.rep_num = r.rep_num; o.customer_num = c.customer_num; ol.order_num = o.order_num; and i.item_num = ol.item_num.

FYI:  reps are found in the rep table and description is found in the item table. 
My code that is not working:

select distinct upper(r.last_name) as rep_lname, 
upper(i.description)as description

from rep r,customer,orders,order_line,item i

where exists
(select i.description from item where i.description = 'ROCKING HORSE');

Comment: As it's homework, I'll give you a nudge in the right direction... You should read about `JOIN`s.

Comment: You missed the join conditions - the "they are connected as follows" part of your question. Also, your `WHERE` condition is incorrect and would return true for all records.

Comment: Previously, I had tried it with the join conditions:

Comment: Previously, I had tried it with the join conditions, on a similar problem, but the tutor had informed me that it was not necessary.  Also, if it's in there, then the 'where exists' command does not work.  If I put the joins back in, how else can I do the last part of the problem?

Comment: The code previously tried was:  select distinct upper(r.last_name) as rep_lname,
upper(i.description)as description
from rep r,customer c,orders o,order_line ol,item i
where c.rep_num = r.rep_num
and o.customer_num = c.customer_num
and ol.order_num = o.order_num
and i.item_num = ol.item_num
and i.description ='ROCKING HORSE'; [this also does not yield anything].  How should I update my where condition?

Comment: Well now you're very close. You just need to do the last part of your question's title i.e. *ensure both sides are in UPPER case for comparison*. If that still doesn't yield data, we'll need to look into your data setup. Maybe rocking horse is just a part of the description, not whole.

Comment: I figured it out!  Here is the code that worked:  select distinct upper(r.last_name) as rep_lname,
upper(i.description)as description
from rep r,customer c,orders o,order_line ol,item i
where c.rep_num = r.rep_num
and o.customer_num = c.customer_num
and ol.order_num = o.order_num
and i.item_num = ol.item_num
and i.description in (select description
      from item
      where item_num ='FD11');

Comment: This just gives you reps who sold that specific item. If there's more than one part with that description it wouldn't return that data. Also, you don't need an inner query when you're selecting that table for JOIN anyway